# How to revert a phabricator patch

Tags: phabricator

I have phabricator patch , which i merged successfully to master.How can I revert the patch from UI ? Is it possible to revert it using UI ?

Answer (score 3):

Phabricator is for reviewing code, not for editing it.  It is not possible to make arbitrary changes to your repositories from the Phabricator UI.  To do that, you need to go back to your client side tools - `git revert` and `arc diff` (or if you think a revert does not need reviewing; `git push`).

Answer (score 0):

This will stay in your history but you can kind of revert to a previous diff.

Say you have phab revision `<revision>` and the last good diff id is `<diff_id>`.

```
git checkout <branch>
arc patch --diff <diff_id>
```

This will create a branch `<arcpatch_revision>`. To update your revision with a sqashed commit,

```
git checkout <arcpatch_revision>
arc diff <master-branch> --update <revision>
```